# Is there wifi in Astana Airport (Kazakhstan)?

Tags: wifi, kazakhstan, astana, tse

I have several hours stopover there tomorrow night. I'm debating sleeping in the airport or sleeping in a hotel - I can sleep anywhere, but if there's wifi in the airport that would seal the deal for me :D

However I can't seem to find out definitively if there is wifi in the airport - free or not - the wiki article is rather sparse.

Comment: I think this is [`General Reference`](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/217/what-should-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-covered-by-google-wikipedia/218#218)-type of question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According the official site](http://www.astanaairport.kz/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=257&Itemid=379&lang=en):

> The passengers and visitors of the airport have an opportunity of wireless internet access.
>   “AERONET” and service on  Wi-Fi internet access are on the 2nd floor in the waiting hall.

Comment: Better yet, the entire airport has 'Welcome to Astana Airport' wifi, and it's fast! :)

Comment: Info from 2019: The wifi works very well there.

Comment: Yes, it's for free, but the speed is a bit slow